# Finite difference method for the Heston model using the ADI scheme

Tags: programming, stochastic-volatility, heston, finite-difference-method

I am trying to implement the ADI FDM scheme for the heston and I am following [The Heston Model and Its Extensions in Matlab and C#](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118656471). They have the scheme:

$$U'(t) = \textbf{L}U(t),$$

$$\textbf{L} = A_0 + A_1 + A_2$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbf{A}_0=\rho \sigma v S\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S \partial v}\right)_{N \times N} \\
& \mathbf{A}_1=(r-q) S\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{N \times N}+\frac{1}{2} v S^2\left(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S^2}\right)_{N \times N}-\frac{1}{2} r(U)_{N \times N} \\
& \mathbf{A}_2=\kappa(\theta-v)\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial v}\right)_{N \times N}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 v\left(\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial v^2}\right)_{N \times N}-\frac{1}{2} r(U)_{N \times N} 
\end{aligned}
$$

In their matlab code for the NON-uniform grid, they have:

[image]

The issue I have is that they don’t include the $\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial S \partial v}$ component. My guess is that is we utilise something like this (in python):

```
I_sv = np.where(csv==1)[0]

for k in range(length(I_sv)):
    
    d_vs = (Si[I[k+1]] - Si[I[k]]) * (Vi[I[k]]- Vi[I[k-Ns]])
    derSV[I[k],I[k-Ns+1]] = -Vi[I[k]] * Si[I[k]] / (4*d_vs)
    
    d_vs = (Si[I[k+1]] - Si[I[k]]) * (Vi[I[k+Ns]]- Vi[I[k]])
    derSV[I[k],I[k+Ns+1]] = Vi[I[k]] * Si[I[k]] / (4*d_vs)
    
    d_vs = (Si[I[k]] - Si[I[k-1]]) * (Vi[I[k+Ns]]- Vi[I[k]])
    derSV[I[k],I[k+Ns-1]] = -Vi[I[k]] * Si[I[k]] / (4*d_vs)
    
    d_vs = (Si[I[k]] - Si[I[k-1]]) * (Vi[I[k]]- Vi[I[k-Ns]])
    derSV[I[k],I[k-Ns-1]] = Vi[I[k]] * Si[I[k]] / (4*d_vs)
```

This is based on the fact that for their UNIFORM grid, they used:

[image]

So I have used the similar format of the uniform grid by adjusting $dv$ & $ds$. But have an error % of about 10%, which is quite large. Anyone have any ideas?